# Using @import in CSS files

Tags: css, import

OK, I get it, CSS files should be grouped to reduce HTTP requests.

My question is whether the @import method does a good work?

Also, can I somehow group print and screen stylesheets?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose `<link>` over `@import`:

- [Best Practices for Speeding Up Your Web Site](http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#csslink)
- [Don't use @import](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2009/04/09/dont-use-import/)